# Improve visibility of "101010" button?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown

It's no secret that new users have trouble formatting their code as code, i.e. indenting it with four spaces. I think the terse help text off to the right could be improved a bit, but even if that were to happen, most people probably won't read it anyway.

Recently I have come to notice that even active users don't know about the "101010 button" in the toolbar though. Most recent example: [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301054/post-call-to-a-php-function), a near-10k'er.

> "oh, I never "seen" that 101010 button and always formatted all sources manually here or in my notepad :-S"
>
> "It was a lot of pain to format sql in pony-style with millions presses of space button. Btw, I've seen it is a button but haven't idea what is it for and did not want to discover it. Meanwhile I've used link, quote, and picture buttons a lot of times. :-)"

I think the visibility/discoverability of the toolbar (buttons) may need to be enhanced, and/or a more visible introduction should be provided for newbies. Of course I realize this can only go so far, and especially on a site for programmers, users are expected to bring a bit curiosity and sense for discovery with them...
Just my 1.68 ¥.

Comment: PS, unrelated bug discovered on same page: Inline text highlighting doesn't work with a trailing interrobang... "`Even _you_‽`" ;)

Comment: please do not abuse the `<kbd>` formatting style; I will pull the CSS for it (again) if I see it happening

Comment: @Jeff But... but... it looks like a button! :o)

Comment: Related: [Change icon of Code Sample button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72509/change-icon-of-code-sample-button) -- the label has changed from `101010` to `{ }`.

Answer (score 4):

> I think the visibility/discoverability of the toolbar (buttons) may need to be enhanced

I don't see how we could do that without damaging the experience for everyone else.

> and/or a more visible introduction should be provided for newbies.

this violates the first law of the universe: Users Don't Read.

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a85dd8f2970b-pi))</sub>

Comment: *sigh* I agree... What about providing a "Format your code by [indenting it](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)!" comment preset and a screenshot of the toolbar with arrows on the editing help page at least? I guess I'm just tired of writing the same comment again and again.

Comment: Now it's status-completed, but where can I see the improved button?

Comment: @kop on any trilogy site but you may need to hard-refresh for the next few days -- we set a far-forward expiration of at least 7 days on static content