# Did the icon for code formatting change to curly braces?

Tags: support, user-interface, code-formatting, editor

Did the icon for `CODE` change to curly braces?

Comment: @Radp ~ I kinda liked the old title ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

See here: [Change icon of Code Sample button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72509/change-icon-of-code-sample-button)
and here: [Improve visibility of "101010" button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71130/improve-visibility-of-101010-button)

Answer (score 2):

It did.  One of the painful transitions that the previous forum I used to post to went through.  They changed it from a toolbar button that used to say "code" to a `</>` icon.  Even though any kind of question on that site was completely off topic if it talked about web questions, there was another site for that.  Strange.

Undiscoverable for young programmers that code is made up from zeroes and ones these days, maybe.  Or that { } means *code* to a non-curly brace language programmer.  Very hard to make everybody happy, other than that old button that used to say 'code'.  It worked, nice short word in English.  But not sexy.

It can't be a real problem, is it?

Comment: :) It is not a real problem. I missed the memo from @JeffAtwood and @JoelSpolsky on the icon change. The other day, when I was formatting somebody's question, I had no idea where my `1010` icon had gone.